# How to crop a single pdf file into separate page pdf's using command line tools?

Tags: pdf

I have a single pdf file with three pages in it I need to turn this pdf into three seperate pdf pages is there any command line tool or script to do this. I am trying with pdftk, pdfcrop, and GS but so far nothing has worked out

Example: one.pdf has 1 page and that page has 3 pages [image: one.pdf]in it. I need to divide this page into 3 seperate pages

Comment: What you're describing isn't cropping, reworded your question to improve your chance of answers.

Answer (score 3):

As far I understand you have three pdf pages stitched together side-by-side, constituting a single pdf page and you want separate any page into a single pdf page

as follows:
[image: 3 pages into 1]

**podofobox**  (from **podofoutils**)

- http://podofo.sourceforge.net/tools.html

> Usage: **podofobox [inputfile] [outpufile] [box] [left] [bottom] [width] [height]**
>
> Box is one of media crop bleed trim art Give values * 100 as
> integers (avoid locale headaches with strtod)

May be a tool to perform this task

take the mediabox info of your input pdf (for instance, with **pdfinfo**). You need to know the size (width and height) of your input pdf (having the three pages stitched side-by-side into one)

in my example, we have a 3-pages-side-by-side pdf

- http://ge.tt/1gZkUcI/v/0

whose width and height are:

> pdfinfo input.pdf | grep "Page size" Page size:      1785 x 841 pts

this is a 3-pages-side-by-side created stitching together 3 A4 size pdf pages

so, in order to get the width of a any single page constituting the **input.pdf** we need to divide (being known the height = **841 points**) **1785 by 3** = **595**

see grid I drawn

[image: grid]

at this point we write this little one liner script

```sh
for i in `seq 0 59500 119000`; do  podofobox  input.pdf  $i-out.pdf media  $i 0 59500 84100; done
```

**explanation**: *the script produces three single pdf pages, starting from 0 and finishing to 1190 points, **0**, **595** and **1190**, are the starting points of any of single pages stitched together*. values are multiplied by 100 (needed by **podofobox** syntax)

this is an example for a pdf constituted of 3 A4 pages stitched side-by-side, if your page has different geometry, you simply need to divide by three and modify the script

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is what I use for all my CLI graphics:

```
convert foo.pdf foo-%01d.pdf
```

This produces three separate PDF files:

```
foo-0.pdf
foo-1.pdf
foo-2.pdf
```

Comment: I have to seperate a single page into 3 seperate pages

Comment: Beware that for PDF files with images in them, `convert` may drastically reduce the quality of those images/scans.

Answer (score -1):

Try using pdftk's 'burst' option.

```
example:
pdftk input.pdf burst
```

You can also use `gs` (ghostscript) `imagemajick`, `graphicsmajick` and I'd expect `cups` could also do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the burst option with pdftk. From the man page...

burst

Splits a single, input PDF document into individual pages. Also creates a report named doc_data.txt which is the same as the output from dump_data. If the output section is omitted, then PDF pages arenamed: pg_%04d.pdf, e.g.: pg_0001.pdf, pg_0002.pdf, etc. To name these pages yourself, supply a printf-styled format string in the output section. For example, if you want pages named: page_01.pdf, page_02.pdf, etc.,pass output page_%02d.pdf to pdftk.
Encryption can be applied to the output by appending output options such as owner_pw, e.g.:
pdftk in.pdf burst owner_pw foopass